# WebPack encore configuration for VueJS

Tags: symfony, webpack, vue.js, webpack-encore

I have the following error when I load a page from a basic symfony App with VueJS and the bundle Webpack encore provided by symfony

`[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.`

So I need to change the alias of VueJS into webpack with this :

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js'
  }
}
```

But I didn't find anything into Webpack Encore to change this settings.

Webpack Encore : http://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does adding this line to your package.json solve the problem?

```
"browser": {
   "vue": "vue/dist/vue.common"
}
```

This is a special field for bundlers. So here we are replacing the default runtime-only release of vue by its compiler-included build.

> When you specify a single string for the browser field, it will
>   replace main and be the module entry point. The main field specifies
>   the entry point to the module so by replacing it, you replace the
>   entry point when the module is packaged by a bundler for browser use.

See the spec: https://github.com/defunctzombie/package-browser-field-spec

Comment: I added an explanation (I had no idea myself how it worked).